# Dedicated network interface for OpenVPN

Tags: networking, iptables, network-interface

I'm trying to use an OpenVPN client service to serve a vpn connection over specific application. In my case I want to setup my tor and only tor connection to go over vpn. Should How would I achieve this? I tried to add a link with `ip link add`, including `tuntap` and `dummy` (I wasted so much time to this interface I'm ashamed of it) interfaces. But when I get OpenVPN to use `tun0` interface by specifying `dev tun0` in `/etc/openvpn/client.conf` for some reason it leaked onto my `eth0` interface, confirmed this by `curl https://ipconfig.me/ip`.
My setup if this could help is: WSL2.0, Debian 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar to keep OpenVPN from interfering with SSH and other services, using network namespaces and veth devices. Summary of the steps from [my blog post a few years ago](https://muru.dev/2020/12/03/poking-pi-ii.html):

1. Set up the namespace and enter it:

   ```bash
   NS_NAME=vpn
   ip netns add "$NS_NAME"
   ip netns exec "$SHELL"
   ln -s /proc/1/ns/net /var/run/netns/default
   ```

   Here, we create a new network namespace named "`vpn`", and start a shell in it. Since the default namespace probably
   doesn't have a name, we set a name for it (`default`).
2. Create the veth pair and move one to the default namespace (we're already in a shell in the new namespace, so the devices are created in it):

   ```
   ip link add dev veth1 mtu 1500 type veth peer name veth2 mtu 1500
   ip link set dev veth2 netns default
   ```
3. Bring up our veth interfaces and assign them IPs:

   ```
   ip addr add dev veth1 10.0.0.1/24
   ip link set veth1 up
   ip netns exec default ip link set veth2 up
   ```
4. Route to the external network via your proper network interface (here, I'm assuming it's IP is 192.168.1.2) and
   route back:

   ```
   ip route add 192.168.1.2/32 dev veth1
   ip route add default via 192.168.1.2
   ip netns exec default ip route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev veth2
   ```
5. Set up packet forwarding using iptables:

   ```
   ip netns exec default iptables -A FORWARD -i veth2 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
   ip netns exec default iptables -A FORWARD -o veth2 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
   ip netns exec default iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
   ```
6. Enable IPv4 forwarding using `sysctl`

   ```
   sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```

Start OpenVPN in this network namespace (for example, by running the `openvpn` command itself here, or by using
systemd to link it to this namespace), and then run any services that need the VPN in the same namespace.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I think I'm almost there? my configuration for openvpn service in `openvpn@client`, so I renamed the override dir to `/etc/systemd/system/openvpn@client.service.d/`. I have found this line in your blog post "(here, I’m assuming it’s IP is 192.168.1.2.)". Does this mean I need to route a specific way to the remote server that I'm using for openvpn? Currently my log shows `read UDPv4 [EHOSTUNREACH]: No route to host (fd=5,code=113)` and I have zero idea why.

Comment: Sorry, got it, its ip address from my `ip route`, replacing the route and ip address, I still get the same error. Output from `ip route`:
default via 172.21.192.1 dev eth0 proto kernel ||| 10.0.0.0/24 dev veth2 scope link ||| 172.21.192.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.21.203.14

Comment: also tried using `172.21.203.14/20` from `inet 172.21.203.14/20 brd 172.21.207.255 scope global eth0` from `ip a` output

Comment: Got it, thank you! Now I have to figure out how to bind a port on my local network. Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry, 192.168.0.2 is the IP of your system in the network that gives it internet access. So this tells the network namespace to route to the internet via that network. In your case I'd say that's eth0 address instead (but with /32). Good to know your figured it out